# Freezing OS - need advice for debugging

Tags: windows-7, cpu, freeze, gpu

My Windows 7 PC recently started to freeze randomly. No hardware or major software changes were made, and no specific circumstances I can locate the freezing depending on. My first suspect is the GPU, but any FurMark stress-test runs well. However, when the hanging occurs, my secondary monitor is not showing the mouse pointer, the cursor itself becomes distorted. The final step is the OS freezes totally, no blue-screen, just nothing responds, even the CapsLock and NumLock dies.

As I use it for working (PS, Indd, 3Dsmax, etc) I tried to stress-test the setup, I let it render a huge image and started a FurMark benchmark at the same time for an hour, without any problem. I have the feeling maybe the hanging occurs more on near-idle state. CPUID shows >90 °C when idle, isn't it too high? It drops on any stress instantly, to around 45°C on full processor capacity.

Any advice is very welcome, how can I locate the problem. Thanks in advance.

CPUID chart:

[image: pic]

FurMark example:

[image: pic]

Setup:

- i5-2500K @3.3Ghz
- ASUS P8P67-M Pro
- 16Gb RAM
- GeForce GTX 460
- Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit

Comment: Are your drivers up to date? Does the problem persist if you disconnect the second screen?

Comment: Try changing the thermal grease on your chips. Not every of them necessarily has a thermal sensor so you wouldn't even know about overheating. Do it with north and south bridge or PCH or whatever too, not only the CPU. I had some nasty stuff going on with my notebook and was troubleshooting some crazy stuff too

Comment: you may have something in the event logs, please check it. did you disabled auto reboot in startup and recovery option under advanced system settings?

Answer (score 0):

When CAP LOCKS dies, you have a hardware issue.

Check those 5 steps:

**Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first"**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504#method3

**Overclocking:** Disable overclocking to see whether the issue occurs when the system is run at the correct speed.

**Check the memory:** Verify the memory by using a memory checker. Verify that each memory chip is the same speed and that it is configured correctly in the system.

**Power supply:** Make sure that the power supply has enough wattage to appropriately handle the installed devices. If you added memory, installed a newer processor, installed additional drives, or added external devices, such devices can require more energy than the current power supply can provide consistently.

**Overheating:** Check whether the system is overheating by examining the internal temperature of the hardware.

**Defaults:** Reset the system back to the system defaults to see whether the issues occur when the system is running in its default configuration.